# Can't create a new Android Virtual Device (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, dalvik

I am using Tools > Android > AVD Manager > Create Virtual Device. After hitting "finish", I am brought back to the "Create Virtual Device" window, with a few new entries in the Event Log which are NullPointerExceptions. Screenshots added to show what's happening.

[image: I hit finish on this window]

[image: Brought back to this window]

[image: Event Log]